# Can a 21 years old revert sister lead her 16,17,18 years old brothers who would like to take part in ramadan, prayers and convert to islam in prayers?

Tags: salat, women, sunnah

Assalamu Alaikum waramatullah wabarakatuh, I am a 21 years old revert sister, from a Christian family recently I noticed my brother and two cousins are interested in my religion, my brother who is 17 has met with me with his intention to fast Ramadan and pray but he doesn't know how to or even know what to say, he says he will pray together with me.. is it permissible if I lead the prayer or if we pray on the same row, I do not understand how to go about it, thank you.

Assalam Alaikum.

Answer (score 0):

You can teach him how to pray by telling him what words to say and what actions to do, and correcting him when he makes any mistakes. He can also observe you and even imitate you. However any such prayer will be a teaching experience and not be a valid congregational prayer. After he converts and learns to pray then he would be the one leading the prayer if you decide to pray together in a personal congregation.